# How to provide theme override for stylesheet conditionally included by a module

Tags: 7, theming

I have a module that conditionally includes a stylesheets using `#attached` on a render array it outputs. (By *conditionally* I'm meaning that sometimes the module adds the attached css, sometimes not; I'm not referring to conditional stylesheets as in "is it IE9".)

The render array the module outputs includes the following:

```
$output['#attached'] = array(
  'css' => array(
    'tiles-styles.css' => array(
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/tiles-styles.css',
      'type' => 'file',
    ),
  ),
);
```

In my theme, I have css under a `css/` directory. I want to override both these, but only when they are required.

It seems that by adding

```
css[tiles-styles.css][data] = 'tiles-styles.css'
```

to my `theme.info` file I can get my file included, and it overrides the
module-provided one. However, doing this *also* includes this stylesheet on
every page load, which is unnecessary.

Is there a way to override the stylesheet but only if the stylesheet was included in the first place?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I'd wonder if it was worthwhile if the alternative CSS is under a few hundred lines as unless you're running a really lean site because most people will be caching the CSS in their browser and having different style sheets will invalidate the cache.  That said I can imagine lots of scenarios where you would want to do this, so just a thought really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by implementing `hook_css_alter` as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
function mytheme_css_alter(&$css) {
  if (isset($css['tiles-styles.css'])) {
    $css['tiles-styles.css']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme')
                                       . '/css/tiles-styles.css';
  }
}
```